# MYSQL: SQL query to get the value of autoincrement field

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table.  The primary key is `id` and its auto incremented.
Now when I insert a new record, I need to get the id with which the record was updated.
How can I do that?  If i use the query...

```
select max(id) from table_name
```

...after executing I can get the id.  But can I be sure that its the id of the record that was just inserted?  Because many people will be using the app at same time.

I am using php and mysql.

Can ayone provie me a sample code snippet in php with mysql?

Comment: It appears you are just starting out with PHP and MySQL.  You will find that the PHP Manual (http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is invaluable and very clear.  The MySQL manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) is also extensive.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find out what the newest ID from an auto increment column is, you just have to run the [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function right after your insert query.

Like so:

```
//--connection already made to database
//--now run your INSERT query on the table
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (foo_column) VALUES ('everlong')");

//-- right after that previous query, you run this
$newest_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

And now `$newest_id` will contain the ID of the latest row inserted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the MySQLi PHP extension, the command you want is [`mysqli_insert_id`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you can do this

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

In php you can call [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 1):

Using the same connection, run this query next:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Your database driver may have a convenience function for that.

Read the docs.

Comment: what do u mean my using the same connection?
Can u giv me sample code in php with mysql

Comment: Same connection means before you close or start another connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get the value of the next auto_increment value (given that you already connected to the server and selected the db;

```
$query = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$auto_incr_val = mysql_result($result, 0, 'Auto_increment');
echo $auto_incr_val;
```

This will give you the value that will be used next in the auto_increment column.
EDIT: I'm sorry.. That wasn't your question....

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in PHP:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE", $link);
$inserted_id = mysql_insert_id($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

```
show create table
```

contains information you need in last string